# Unlocking encrypted MacBook Pro Admin user

Tags: encryption, macbook-pro

Is it possible to unlock a MacBook Pro admin user if the computer is encrypted? If so will all data be lost when trying to change the password?

How would I go about changing the admin user password on an encrypted MacBook Pro?

Comment: I am 90% sure if you change the password with a user with access to sudo (i.e. root) you will be unable to access your encrypted data.  Otherwise, anyone with access could access your files.   You will want to recall your password, decrypt your drive, before you do anything

Comment: Changing the admin password won't necessarily change the encryption password. You'll end up needing both to access the machine. If it's a T2 machine it may not even let you get that far. Best to decrypt, change, encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

My go to when unlocking macbook pros is Recovery mode "resetpassword" it simply resets the admin password of the computer.
For encrypted it might be different. Maybe making a second admin account from single user mode would work? Hope this helps -NMD